# If a transfer function G(s) is bibo stable, is it also asymptotically stable?

Tags: control-theory, stability-theory

My understanding was that asymptotic stability is a stronger condition than BIBO stability, so the statement is false. However, my professor insists that this statement is true. Can anyone help explain?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The statement is only true when it is applied to linear systems that are completely controllable and observable (aka no pole-zero cancellation in the transfer function G(s)).

Comment: Your understanding is wrong, asymptotic stability is defined for systems without input, BIBO stability for systems with input, so they can't be compared directly. There exist generalizations of asymptotic stability to systems with inputs (like input to state stability), but generally it is not correct to think of asymptotic stability as a stronger condition than BIBO stability.

Comment: It depends on the context. In the context of transfer function classes (prior to state-space methods) those concepts are equivalent. They are both equivalent to the fact that the poles lie in the open left half-plane. As others have pointed out, they start to differ when taken out of this context and considered according to their true and correct definitions.